# google cloud iot - connection refused thorugh mqtt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, iot

I am working on google iot with raspberry pi 4. After following [this tutorial](http://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi), I succeeded to connect to GCP with mqtt at first time. After that I got an error on connect:

*connection refused: bad user name or password*.

Is there any solution to this error?

Comment: Which tutorials were you following? How did you set up your authentication?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi I am using this as tutorials.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the error? This post might help, [things to triple check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889957/11928117). Unfortunately, I don't have the material to follow your tutorial so I can't reproduce it but are you able to do our [Using gateways tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways) where you can create a device?